# How to use the master version of bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I am curious about how bundler (https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler) works. So I cloned the repository. However I am not able to figure out what I need to do so that when I do `bundle install` **ruby should use the bundler which I have cloned and not the gem already installed.**

I guess I need to add my repo path somewhere so that when ruby is looking for `bundler` it picks up cloned bundler and not the gem bundler.

I tried a few things. but nothing worked. I use rvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do

```
gem build bundler.gemspec
```

which generates a .gem file and install this with rubygems

```
gem install bundler-1.1.0.gem
```

than you are using your own fork of bundler

Comment: Let me give that a try. one thought. Using this style I can play with bundler but every single time I add a puts I need to redo the whole thing. Was wondering how the bundler core team works . I am sure they use some PATH trickery to make it all work without actually building a gem.  But this will work in the meantime.